# Codename One - "Unknown chart type Line"

Tags: codenameone

In Codename One, I have a form that displays a chart. The chart has two series, one of type Line and one of type Scatter. The chart no longer displays. I ran logcat and the following appeared in the log.

```
[EDT] 0:8:55,339 - Codename One revisions: 7dd4e7d08b3442d90959477ee52a5ae8c4361b29
[EDT] 0:8:55,343 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Unknown chart type Line
```

My code is:

```
CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[] types = new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef[]{
        new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.TYPE, 0),
        new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(ScatterChart.TYPE, 1)
    };

CombinedXYChart chart = new CombinedXYChart(xyMSD, xyMSR, types);
```

Is there something I can do to rectify?

Comment: Looking at the code it seems that type is expected as: `LineChart.class.getName()`. Which is weird since we use this exact code in our demo... Does that workaround solve the problem?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog thanks. I've changed the line to: new CombinedXYChart.XYCombinedChartDef(LineChart.class.getName(), 0), and received this error (in the simulator) Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Unknown chart type com.codename1.charts.views.LineChart.

Comment: That's my bad, I didn't read the code correctly. The original code should have worked. I think this might be related to the gradle 8 migration. As a temporary workaround try switching this off as explained [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/1b06naw/we_will_switch_to_grdale_8_by_default_for_android/). We're looking into this.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog thanks. I've made those changes, added two Build Hints, but can't yet test. I have another blocking problem regarding ConnectionRequest and Cookies (hopefully unrelated). Once I solve that I'll come back and test.

Comment: We made a couple of experimental build hints can you try both and see if one of them solves the problem (if both are enabled then only one of them will work):
`android.disableR8FullMode=true` and `android.disableR8=true`.

Comment: These build hints should no longer be necessary. We made a fix for the servers and this should work now.